# Java - Reading From FIle

Tags: java, file

I am trying to read some lines from a file in Java. I have 4 lines in the file, but the problem is that it reads only 2 of the lines. Here's the code:

```
BufferedReader flux_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("abc.txt")));
String line;
while (flux_in.readLine() != null)
{
    line = flux_in.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because you are calling `readLine` twice as often as you should.

Your first call inside the the `while` condition just threw the line away.

```
BufferedReader flux_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("abc.txt"))); 
String line;
while ((line = flux_in.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It does read all of them, although not quite in the way you'd like.

```
BufferedReader flux_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("abc.txt"))); 
String line;
while (flux_in.readLine()!=null)  //one line is read here
{

    line = flux_in.readLine();  //the next one here
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the call in the loop test consumes a line, and then the call n the loop body consumes another line. So it would only print every other line.

```
String s = null;
while ((s = flux_in.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` is stateful and remembers what has been read from the file already.  Every call of `readLine()` moves the cursor to the next line.  You are calling `readLine()` twice per line: in the `while` loop and in the `line` assignment.  Try this instead:

```
String line = flux_in.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = flux_in.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the line twice (in the while *condition* and in the while *loop*, so it's displaying one and then skipping the next. Change your code to this:

```
try {
    BufferedReader flux_in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("abc.txt")); 
    String line;
    while ((line = flux_in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(line);
} catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("Error"); }
```