# Read from file in managed bean

Tags: file, web, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I work in JDeveloper and created a Web Fusion Application. I have a managed bean and in one of it's methods I want to read data from my custom file (just like Scanner does it). How can I do it? Where should I place this file in my project?

Comment: You want the user to upload it or just read a file located within your application?

Comment: Just a file located within my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a folder within your Web Content. Then copy your file manually there (go to c:/Oracle/MiddleWare/Jdeveloper/Jdev/myWork/YourApp/ViewController...). Back in JDeveloper refresh your application and you should see the new file inside your new folder. Then you refer to it simply as "/MyFolder/myfile.txt" or anything else.

Edited

```
public ServletContext getContext() {
    return (ServletContext)getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getContext();
}
ServletContext context = getContext(); 
InputStream fs = context.getResourceAsStream("/Folder/file");
```

Comment: Just followed your advice. But during this code
`    try
    {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/folder/file.txt"));
      while (scan.hasNext())
        res.append(scan.nextLine());
      scan.close();
      return res.toString();      
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
      return "error";
    }`
FileNotFoundException is thrown. I'm so sad :_(

Comment: Try this: ServletContext context = getContext();
        InputStream fs = context.getResourceAsStream("/Folder/file");

Comment: Yep, it seems to be the solution, but I tried 
    ServletContext context = (ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
but it throws ClassCastException. I don't know where to take ServletContext

Answer (score 0):

You mean reading from file - just use Java File API

[Java read from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757032/java-reading-from-file)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned Scanner class. But the problem is where to put this file